# Injecting secret from AWS SecretsManager in CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, environment-variables, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to inject some credentials from AWS SecretsManager into my Container in AWS CodeBuild and I'm stuck.

I've created the secret and I'm referencing it in my `buildspec.yaml` like this

```yaml
version: 0.2
env:
  secrets-manager:
    DB_PASSWORD: "dbcreds:password"
    DB_USER: "dbcreds:user"
```

What would be the commands in the `build` step?

I'm happy to work through a guide, but I haven't found a fitting one yet.

Answer (score 0):

`env` creates environment variables. So you would refer to them later on in the `buildspec.yaml` as you would normally do for any other bash environmental variable: `${DB_PASSWORD}` or `${DB_USER}`.